# Proving that a function f is a kernel.

Tags: inner-products, machine-learning

The theory states that $$f(x,y)\\ \text{with} \ x\ \text{and}\ y \in R^n$$   in order to be a valid kernel, beside being symmetric, has to be an inner product in a suitable space.

Is this latter requirement equivalent to claim that the following Matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
f(x,x) & f(x,y) \\
f(y,x) & f(y,y) 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

is semidefinite positive for any pair x and y? 
If not, why?

Comment: I think you need to check this for an arbitrary number of datapoints. You are checking for two datapoints. I'm not sure if this is enough.

Comment: Some examples here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35634/how-to-prove-that-the-radial-basis-function-is-a-kernel

Comment: But why do when need to check for an arbitrary number of points?

Comment: Because that's Mercer's theorem tells us to do!

Comment: ahh still not clear

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem#Introduction

Comment: Thank you. So basically Mercer Theorems requires f(x,y) to be semidefinite positive for n arbitrary data points, that's identical to check the existence of the Gram Matrix.  In order to do so, we check that the matrix defined above is semidefinite positive for arbitrary n value, and not just 2. Otherwise the whole reasoning doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87936/discussion-between-tommaso-bendinelli-and-kenny-wong).